# CloudKit and GameCenter in a game?

Tags: ios, game-center, cloudkit

I am working on a game.  It will use Game Center for multiplayer.  I would like to be able to use CloudKit for storing levels and the local CloudKit container for storing game progress.  The problem is that this requires to different accounts.  Any ideas on how to link them together?

Answer (score 3):

I struggled with this recently when building in syncing to my game Qiktionary. At first I associated single player game data with the currently logged in Game Center player. So when I started working on sync, I was associating the single player game data in CloudKit with the Game Center player by using a separate CKRecordZone (in the private db) for each Game Center player.

I ended up abandoning that approach because it turns out that causes some behaviour that looks to the user like data loss. For example, GC Player A is logged into your game and plays 10 single player games (or in your case, levels). Later they happen to log out of Game Center, and even later than that they come back to your game and since they are logged out, they no longer see their 10 games played. It's not obvious that the game data is there but just "missing" because they are now logged out of GC.

I did some research and most other games don't work like that. Single player game progress is not linked to the logged in Game Center player. Which means that the single player game data in CloudKit shouldn't be linked to the Game Center player either.

This is even how the `GKSavedGame` API from GameKit works. According to [the docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/GameKit_Guide/SavedGames/SavedGames.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008304-CH19-SW1):

> Saved games are tied to the iCloud account, not the Game Center account